# In Eclipse how to refer to "home" directory (~ doesn't work)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm adding "includes" for my project. In "GCC C++ Compiler/Includes" i want to add corresponding directories. I've tried to use "~/blabla/include" but I can't compile, it seems Eclipse doesn't recognize it.

I don't want to use full path because I store them in svn and later use on several computers.

Is it possible to refer "home" somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build Variable HOME is added by default use ${HOME} to refer home folder. Right click on project and click on properties.

Refer screen shots below
[image]
[image]